# Why my lists are not Joining When I try to Append Them Python

Tags: python, for-loop, append

```
import csv
filename='songdata.csv'
reader=csv.reader(open(filename,'r'))
header=next(reader)

data=[]
for row in reader:
    # row=[Song, Artist, Year, Tempo, Hotness, Duration, Key, Loudness, Mode]
    Song=row[0]
    Artist=row[1]
    Year=int(row[2])
    Tempo=float(row[3])
    Hotness=float(row[4])
    Duration=float(row[5])
    Key=int(row[6])
    Loudness=float(row[7])
    Mode=int(row[8])
    data.append([Song, Artist, Year, Tempo, Hotness, Duration, Key, Loudness, Mode])

for tempo in data:
    p=[]
    p.append(tempo[3])
    print p
```

My CSV file has columns for Song, Artist, Year, Tempo, Hotness, Duration, Key, Loudness, Mode. I made an empty list and I am trying to append all of the float values that represent Tempo into this list, but I keep just getting a bunch of separate list values that represent each float. It seems like nothing was actually appended to p. I even tried flattening the result with a function I made a while back, but it didn't have any effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: `for tempo in data:
    p=[]
    p.append(tempo[3])` => `p = []` must be outside the loop!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for tempo in data:
    p=[]
    p.append(tempo[3])
```

doesn't make sense since `p` is reset every time in the loop. So move the init of `p` before the loop.

Better yet: use a *list comprehension* to avoid such bugs:

```
p = [tempo[3] for tempo in data]
```

Comment: Dangit! you knew I was about to post an answer _exactly_ like this, even with the tip about using a list comp ;-) +1

Comment: Thank you very much! That should have been very obvious, but I am still just a beginner.

Comment: @ChristianDean :) without the listcomp it would be less interesting to answer. I repeat and repeat about listcomps because they're not only beautiful but also the best way to avoid side-effect bugs like those ones.